# On the number of solutions of $pq^m \equiv k\bmod{n}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, perfect-powers

It has been shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3160594/existence-of-solutions-for-pqm-equiv-k-bmodn/3160653#3160653) that there exist positive integers $n,k$ such that for all primes $p$ and integers $q\ge 1$, $m\ge 2$, we have
$$
pq^m \not\equiv k\bmod{n}.
$$

$\text{ }$

Hence, let $f(n)$ be the number of $k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $pq^m \equiv k\bmod{n}$, for some prime $p$ and integers $q\ge 1$, $m\ge 2$. (In particular, $f(n) \le n-1$ for some $n$.)

> **Question.** Is it true that there exists $c>0$ such that $f(n) \ge cn$ for all $n$?

Ps. Thanks to Erick Wong for the correction